# Not able to send email using custom template in magento 1.9.2 community edition

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, email-templates

I am trying to send an email in Magento using custom email templates. But I am getting an exception. I have installed SMTP Pro Extension.

I am listing code here:

My config.xml

```
<template>
  <email>
    <custom_abc_email_template  module="custom_abc">
      <label>Custom Template</label>
      <file>custom_abc_templates/customTemplate.html</file>  // this specifies the path where the custom template is located
      <type>html</type>
    </custom_abc_email_template>
  </email>
</template>
```

code of my controller action

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_abc_email_template');
$emailTemplate->setSenderName('custom template');
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('abc@demomail.com');
$emailTemplate->send('abc@demomail.com','Forgot Password');
```

My Template file code

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="action-content">
            <h1>Custom Abc,</h1>
            <p><strong>Your new password is:</strong> trolled</p>
            <p>You can change your password at any time by logging into <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}">your account</a>.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In exception.log

```
2016-04-11T10:03:18+00:00 ERR (3): exception 'Exception' with message
'This letter cannot be sent.' in /var/www/html/MMM/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php:40
```

In aschroder_smtppro.log

```
2016-04-11T10:03:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): Email is not valid for sending, 
this is a core error that often means there's a problem with your email templates.
```

setting of email in backend
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this template

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td class="action-content">
        <h1>Custom Abc,</h1>
        <p><strong>Your new password is:</strong> trolled</p>
        <p>You can change your password at any time by logging into <a href="{{store url='customer/account/'}}">your account</a>.</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the same exception with change to Magento system email setting.
The exception is set in email template code of the plugin (see below).

In Admin select System -> Configuration from top-menu, and go to System - Mail Sending settings. Set "Disable Email Communications" to "No".

```
if (!$this->isValidForSend()) {
    $_helper->log('Email is not valid for sending, this is a core error that often means there\'s a problem with your email templates.');
    Mage::logException(new Exception('This letter cannot be sent.')); // translation is intentionally omitted
    return false; }
```